# How to reference sub collections in mongo db

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to group by objectives in a collection which has data is below format.

```
[unique_id] => 649083802  
[objectives_compleeted_log_queue] => Array (  
)  
[objectives] => Array (      
        [37] => Array (  
            [is_completed] =>   
            [tasks] => Array (  
            [56] => Array (  
                [completed_count] => 0  
                [actions] => Array (  
                    [0] => 0  
                )  
            )  
        )  
    )  
    [96] => Array (  
        [is_completed] =>   
        [tasks] => Array (   
            [123] => Array (  
                [completed_count] => 0  
                [actions] => Array (  
                    [0] => 0  
                )  
            )  
        )  
    )  
    [97] => Array (  
        [is_completed] =>   
        [tasks] => Array (  
            [124] => Array (  
                [completed_count] => 0  
                [actions] => Array (  
                    [0] => 0  
                )  
            )  
        )  
    )
```

I need to group the unique_ids for each of the objectives (37, 96, 97... ) in the above example. Sorry very new to mongo db

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, using dynamic field names in your documents (e.g. `objectives.37`) will reduce your flexibility with indexing and queries. For starters, you won't be able to take advantage of [multi-key indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys).

Nevertheless, we can use [map/reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) to aggregate and count distinct ID's in your existing schema. In the interest of keeping the following examples concise, I shortened the field name to `o` and irrelevant data from the data fixtures.

```
<?php

$m = new Mongo();
$db = $m->test;

$db->foo->drop();
$db->foo->insert(['o' => [36 => [], 63 => [], 64 => []]]);
$db->foo->insert(['o' => [12 => [], 36 => [], 97 => []]]);

$result = $db->command([
  'mapreduce' => 'foo',
  'map' => new MongoCode('
    function() {
      for (var key in this.o) emit(key, { count: 1 });
    }
  '),
  'reduce' => new MongoCode('
    function(key, values) {
      var r = { count: 0 };
      values.forEach(function(v) { r.count += v.count; });
      return r;
    }
  '),
  'out' => ['inline' => 1]
]);

echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Here, we're executing the map function across the entire collection, emitting each unique key within `o` objects that we process. With each emission, the initial value we emit is `{count: 1}`. After mapping, we have a huge pile of emissions consisting of a key and `{count: 1}` pair. Our reduce method is then called to process these intermediary results for distinct keys. Each object in the `values` argument follows the same structure (i.e. the same value we emitted earlier), and we are expected to return a single, reduced value of that same structure.

This script would yield the following output:

```
$ php mr.php 
{
    "results": [
        {
            "_id": "12",
            "value": {
                "count": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "36",
            "value": {
                "count": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "63",
            "value": {
                "count": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "64",
            "value": {
                "count": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "97",
            "value": {
                "count": 1
            }
        }
    ],
    "timeMillis": 17,
    "counts": {
        "input": 2,
        "emit": 6,
        "reduce": 1,
        "output": 5
    },
    "ok": 1
}
```

If you instead re-worked your schema so that `objectives` was an array of nested objects, we can make use of the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/) in MongoDB 2.2+ to compute the same result with less effort:

```
<?php

$m = new Mongo();
$db = $m->test;

$db->foo->drop();
$db->foo->insert(['o' => [['id' => 36], ['id' => 63], ['id' => 64]]]);
$db->foo->insert(['o' => [['id' => 12], ['id' => 36], ['id' => 97]]]);

$result = $db->command([
  'aggregate' => 'foo',
  'pipeline' => [
    ['$project' => ['o' => 1]],
    ['$unwind' => '$o'],
    ['$group' => ['_id' => '$o.id', 'count' => ['$sum' => 1]]],
  ],
]);

echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Here, we use the aggregation pipeline to do three operations in sequence:

- Project the `o` field of scanned documents, which is similar to selecting specific output fields in a find query.
- Unwind each `o` array we come across. Thinking of the pipeline as a stream of documents, we'll have two documents enter this step, each with three nested objects in their respective `o` fields. Unwinding will yield six documents to the next step, with each `o` array field replaced by an element of the array.
- Group all documents in the stream at this point, using the `o.id` field as the grouping identifier and a summation as the group value for each element. For each grouped element, the `count` value field will be increased by one.

This script produces the output:

```
$ php af.php 
{
    "result": [
        {
            "_id": 12,
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": 63,
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": 97,
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": 64,
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": 36,
            "count": 2
        }
    ],
    "ok": 1
}
```